# accessing elements of a tensor with another list of indices in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to access elements of a tensor with another list of indices that I have but currently it seems impossible with straightforward syntax. I wasn't sure whether it is a bug or not, so I post it here to hopefully fix my syntax. My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()
input = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
idx_list = np.array([0,2])
output = input[:, idx_list]

print(sess.run(output))
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1    From
>   merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'strided_slice/stack_1' (op:
>   'Pack') with input shapes: [], [2].

My installed version of tensorflow is tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35 (pip installation).

**Update:**

I do this operation by tf.fn_map, but i really suspect that is the correct way to do indexing:

```
output = tf.transpose(tf.map_fn(lambda x: input[:,x], idx_list),perm=[1,0])
```

**Update:**

There is a specific [issue registered](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206) for this with a nice snippet in the latest comments that can be helpful. Meanwhile this operation is not as easy as numpy ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `tf.gather` and `tf.transpose` as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()
input = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
idx_list = np.array([0,2])
output = tf.transpose(tf.gather(tf.transpose(input),idx_list))
output.eval(session=sess)
```

This prints

```
array([[1, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks! see my updates if you haven't already see the issue on github.